# Изменение модели User в Django

Tags: python, django, orm

Здравствуйте, возникли трудности(возможно с пониманием:)) с изменением модели User в Django. Я расширил модель своим классом

```
class ExtendedUser(User):
    pass
```

И мне необходимо сделать чтобы поле username(наследуемое из User) при создании объекта ExtendedUser было необязательным(по-умолчанию оно обязательно). В код Джанги думаю лезть не стоит =)... а как по-другому сделать не могу сообразить. Помогите)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версия Django какая? Это имеет значение. Если 1.6, то лучше наследоваться не от User, а от AbstractBaseUser. Вот статейка с примером: [Using Configurable User Models in Django 1.5](http://procrastinatingdev.com/django/using-configurable-user-models-in-django-1-5/)

Вот мой рабочий пример:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password=None, name=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
        name=name,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
    )

    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(u"Имя", max_length=100, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(u"Телефон", max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(u"Адрес", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(u'date joined', default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.name, self.patronymic)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Comment: Да, 1.6. Спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

Comment: Тут пара вопросов возникли.(весь код ниже - из статьи)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['twitter_handle']

этого ведь не будет достаточно в моем случае, чтобы при создании нового юзера не требовалось поле **username**? Для того чтоб этого достигнуть -обязательно нужно написать свой менеджер, я правильно понял?

И второй - когда я наследовал от User, то при работе с базой, модели просто джоинились, в данном случае будет тоже самое или же вся инфа о пользователе будет в новой модели?

Comment: Инфа будет в новой таблице в базе, ты наследуешься от абстрактной модели - для нее таблицы не будет, будет одна таблица для конечной модели

Comment: Все, теперь понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, надо переопределить username с blank=True?

```
username = models.CharField('Логин', max_length=30, blank=True, unique=True)
```